# How to convert below mentioned R code to python code?

Tags: python, r

How to convert below mentioned `R` code to `python` code?

```
my_data$class[my_data$category == "WD"] <- "TRUE"
```

Comment: could you please be more specific and provide details what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  is use `numpy.where`

```
import numpy
my_data['category']=numpy.where(my_data.category=="WD",'TRUE,my_data.category)
```

by the way , Please edit and update your question to answer it more better , We are happy to help

Comment: if it worked for you then ... please mark it as correct answer....